# Changing the default text field in xcode

Tags: xcode, default, textfield

I've made a user interface that contains several text fields. When the app launches, xcode  automatically selects the first one. But for the purpose of the app, that's not practical.

How can I force it to start at another text field when launched? I thought maybe an awake from nib could do it but i have no idea what the code would be.

Comment: What’s your target platform: Mac OS X or iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a call to `[myTextField becomeFirstResponder]` (where "myTextField" is the field you want to start with) in your controller's `viewWillAppear` method.